# Where can I ask about oauth plugins for PHP?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What is the appropriate SE site for asking about oauth plugins for PHP?

Comment: So what is your actual question? That is necessary to be able to answer this question.

Comment: ooaapth = oauth?

Comment: @Pat yes, see the tag OP used. Probably using mobile with some funky auto correct.

Comment: I would like to find an OAuth plugin for vanilla PHP that is easy to use and well documented. I have spent several days reading tutorials and articles as well as trying to implement OAuth from several parties. I have tried opauth, googles PHP oauth and f3 opauth plugin. They are all buggy or poorly documented.

Comment: So software recommendations site that is mentioned in the linked question's answer is probably your best bet

Comment: Thanks, all. I will post on the SO software recommendations site.